# Unreal Engine 5 storage permission issue on sdk 33

Tags: android, unreal-engine5

Hi unreal engine save game not working on api 33. It is not asking any runtime permission although it supports upto android 12 devices. What settings need to be done? Please help. I am using ue5.

Comment: Which permissions should be asked?

Comment: storage permission. READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.READ_MEDIA_* nothing is working

Comment: On an Android 13 device you will not ask for read or write external storage. Only for reading media if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same problem with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE while using UE 5.2 with API33(Android 13)

Long story short, change WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE AndroidManifest.xml file to have maxSdkVersion="18" attribute added.

I wrote a detailed write up here in the Unreal Engine Forum:

https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/permission-requiired-you-must-approve-this-premission-in-app-settings-storage/656530/21

Comment: I need those permissions for functionality of my game. This is simply ignoring those permissions. My concern is how can I ask those permissions on android 13 and above with target sdk 33

Comment: Hi Arnab again !

In your orignal post you say your save game is not working on api 33.  How are you trying to save your game and what error do you get?

Comment: Hi Arnab again #2, ok I tested this too - its not working for me.  I saw your post Arnab Sparkle on UE Forum.  I am testing this now too.